# would this be a strong result?

Tags: limits, number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers

Consider the following limit:

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\big|\tau(x)-\text{Li}(x)\big|=0 $$

Where $\tau(x)$ is some way of measuring primes less than a given magnitude, and $\text{Li}(x)$ is the logarithmic integral.

> If this limit was proven would it be a good result on understanding the distribution of primes?

I think so, but I wanted to ask just to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: That one is a theorem, and your $\tau(x)$ is usually called $\pi(x)$. Search for "Prime Number Theorem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti the differences definitely don't go to zero unless im mistaken

Comment: OPS. See here, that claim is false:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178635/lower-bounds-on-the-error-term-of-the-prime-number-theorem

Comment: The absolute differences are larger than $x^{1/2-\varepsilon}$ for infinitely many times

Comment: The correct statement is $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{Li(x)}=1$$ $Li(x)$ is an excellent approximation of $\pi(x)$, under the Riemann hypothesis even extraordinary good.